# Check port before doing bind in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

My program connects to server using three hops and it required three different port address also

I have 5 threads and all simultaneously connecting to server using different port address, but in some case two threads access same port and bind fails.

I am just increment the port address for each hop but for different thread  conflict happens

Is there any function to check port number free so that I can safely assign port for next connection.

Comment: The only portable way to check a port is to either try to connect to it, or try to bind to it.

Comment: How are you sharing which port number to use next?  Sounds like that could be a data race.

Comment: Are you binding the source port for an _outgoing_ connection? With TCP?

Comment: I am using bind function with port number incremented from last success bind